# Extract specific parts from sentence by using infer keyword in Typescript Template Literal?

Tags: typescript, types, type-systems, template-literals

Assume inputting a sentence contains one or two spaces and has the structure `${Verb}${one or two spaces}${Activity}`, how could I extract the `Verb` and `Activity` in Typescript?

```
type Split = ' ' | '  '

type ExtractVerb<S extends string> =
    S extends `${infer Verb}${Split}${infer Activity}`
    ? [Verb, Activity]
    : never;

type Verbs = ExtractVerb<"play chess" | "write  code" | "read hacker  news">
```

I got the result type `["play", "chess"] | ["write", " code" | "code"] | ["read" | "read hacker", "hacker  news" | "news"]`.

Expected: `["play", "chess"] | ["write", "code"] | ["read", "hacker  news"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that `S` is a union, so any type containing it (such as `${infer Verb}${Split}${infer Activity}`) will be considered for both union members. So typescript will then give you both possible results. For `"write  code"` you can split by `' '` and get [`"write"`, `" code"`] or by `'  '` and get [`"write"`, `"  code"`].

You could keep the `Split` strings in a tuple, and run through them until you get a match using a recursive conditional type:

```
type Split = ['  ', ' ']

type ExtractVerb<S extends string, Seprators extends string[] = Split> =
    Seprators extends [infer FirstSeparator, ...infer RestSeparators] ?
        S extends `${infer Verb}${FirstSeparator & string}${infer Activity}`
            ? [Verb, Activity]
            : ExtractVerb<S, RestSeparators & string[]>
        : never

type Verbs = ExtractVerb<"play chess" | "write  code" | "read hacker  news">
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=16&pln=7&pc=56#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYUC8UDaByKUsBo88BdAWACgLRIoBRAD2ACcBDAY2ADUImAjAHhhQIjCADsAJgGcoU5ojEBzQjAhhWwAPZMZI4OOmz5SjMTSwEyAHxoKuXKvUstO4aMkyMCgGY8oAMUQdYEcWDW1CADponz8AJQg5UPCdMwB+O3ssoT0DGQADABIAb1imKG4+AF8SwODk520oADIjJgVFGtKxX3KAQQ5EADdkECr8zKypqDTMSt5CAeBh0bJyaemALjpGVg55wUIEpLUwxtdWuXaTYitJqe2xCCGeCipwaHmZdAZmdi4eAIAEQIFggKBsAAWiSkQKgAB8oECAO7tfS4NiaCQQOGIoFMCAsCRQSHsADWfigT2RsLulHIQA)

Note that this is a [tail recursive type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711), so the compiler should deal reasonably well with it.